# Using Mechanize with Google's 2FA

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve data from a (Google) web service using Mechanize.

If a user does *not* have 2FA (Two Factor Authentication) this code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $email = 'xxxxx';
my $pass = 'xxxxx';

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $time1 = (time - 24 * 60 * 60) * 1000;
my $time2 = (time + 24 * 60 * 60) * 1000;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0/kml?startTime=$time1&endTime=$time2");
$mech->submit_form(fields => { 'Email' => $email, 'Passwd' => $pass, }, );
$mech->content =~ m!.*<gx:coord>(.*?)</gx:coord>!s;
my $coord = $1;
my($lng, $lat) = ($coord =~ /^([-+]?[\d\.]+)[ ,]+([-+]?[\d\.]+)/);
```

If a user has 2FA switched on, after submitting the password the page asks for a 2FA code.  I have a token which generates the code - but I'm not sure how I would submit it.

(NB I've tried using [App Specific Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) - but they don't work for this sort of access.)

1. How can I submit the 2FA code on the second page?
2. Is there any way I can store the cookie so I don't have to use the 2FA token each time?

Comment: I would recommend [authenticating with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and using the Maps API if you want to interact with Google Maps programmatically.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: does the maps api support location history?  from many questions a google search turns up, I suspect it does not

Comment: using the same www mech object for later calls should preserve your cookie.  or store it in a file: `WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "somefilename.dat", autosave => 1 ) )`.  It won't last forever, though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the Maps API does *not* include location history. Hence needing to use this workaround.